# NavigationView elevation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-support-design, android-navigationview

I tried to set the elevation of a NavigationView using both `android:elevation` and `app:elevation`. But neither of them seem to work. I also tried to set the elevation programmatically by using `setElevation(float)`. This also didn't work.

My XML looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    app:elevation="16dp"/>
```

So, how to properly set the elevation of a NavigationView?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I was able to do it in code, but the XML attribute seems to be ignored or overridden by something.

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers,

to remove the drawer shadow, you have to set it from the `DrawerLayout` and not from the `NavigationView` itself!

so from code it will be:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
drawerLayout.setDrawerElevation(0);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use of the codes:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

ere